# New Code in C# and ASP.NET now requiring IE to set Internet Zone setting to low

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I do not even know how to ask this question. Last week I migrated new ASP.NET pages written in C# to production/live site. These pages replaced ASP Classic pages. For some reason people using IE 11 need to set their Internet Zone to "Low" or "Accept All Cookies" (First setting on the Privacy tab in "Internet Options.") I am not using cookies anywhere in my code. I do not want to force people to change this setting but I do not know where to being to look for a solution. A couple of years ago I used cookies in my ASP Classic version, maybe this could be the cause? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
-JG

Comment: Do you use any session variables, or forms authentication?

Comment: Not enough information - rewrite this and provide more information as to what you have done so far. Your guess is as good as anyone else's. You say you don't have cookies in your code - have you _verified_ this using any browser dev tools?

Comment: I do use session variables. Could there be cookies being written and used even if I did not set and use cookies in my code? The code is written by me and me alone.  Thanks.

Comment: Sessions are are a server side concept that are cookies on the client (unless "cookieless" - essentially state is in URLs)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EdSF, I would have chasing my tail for days trying to figure this out. It turns out there are **2 cookies being written by Google Analytics**. I assume GA is being used since we use Google Fiber as our ISP and for our IP addresses. Below is the code I added to disable the Google Analytics cookies, and all cookies.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true" mode="InProc" timeout="30" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
</system.web>
```

Thanks Again
-JG